# Assigning solutions to a variable

Tags: equation-solving, functions

If I do

```
Solve[x+1==0, x]
```

then I get

```
{{x -> -1}}
```

But I want to assign the solution -1 directly before seeing the result, so that

```
a = Some_function[Solve[x+1==0, x]]
```

and a = -1.

Then I will be able to perform something like

```
Abs[Some_function[Solve[x+1==0, x]]]
```

If there is such a function like "Some_function", it will be awesome.

I tried to find one but I couldn't. Regex seems likely to work for this purpose but I couldn't understand regex..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = First[x /. Solve[x + 1 == 0, x]]
```

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't work by itself but gave some hints.   First[First[Solve[x + 1 == 0, x]]]  will at least eliminate the {{ }}  but I still need to eliminate "x ->"

Comment: @user3123767 -- this answer returns `-1`. If you are getting something different, restart your kernel to clear old variable definitions.